# How to avoid Grafana handling NULL values from Google BigQuery as 0

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana

I have the [doitintl BigQuery plugin](https://github.com/doitintl/bigquery-grafana) (v2.0.2) installed for my Grafana instance (v8.2.7).

My SQL query is based on multiple tables and is joined with a full outer join on the timestamp column. Therefore, I have some `null` values returned and they are shown as such in the GCP BigQuery Console.

However, when I run the query in my time series panel, those null values are treated as zeros, leading to a graph that does not make sense.

Is there a way to avoid that behaviour in Grafana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this is a bug of the plugin, nothing from Grafana side nor settings.

However, Grafana has forked the plugin and this issue is fixed (tested with v0.1.10). Therefore, to avoid this issue, use the [Grafana BigQuery datasorce plugin](https://github.com/grafana/google-bigquery-datasource) (note: at the time of writing the plugin is still in beta).